# What is the reaction force of electric force

Tags: forces

I am new for physics and I hope your help for this problem.

According to the newtons third law , there is a reaction for every action with a same magnitude and opposite in direction.

I tried a long time to find the reaction of the electric force. My question is

*is there a reaction for the electric force?

*if the answer is 'yes' where that reaction force forms?

Thanks

Comment: Two general ideas about Newton's third law: (1) The two forces are always of the same type (friction and friction, or electrical with electrical, etc.). (2) There is no such thing as a "reaction." This is bad terminology that is unfortunately firmly entrenched in the cultural consciousness. Neither force is the "action" or the "reaction." They both just exist together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an electron, place another electron near it, then they repel each other. The first electron pushes the other, the other pushes the first one. This is a **mutual** electric force.

You can say it like this: Whatever a (charged) object exerts its (electric) force upon, is pushing back. So the place where the reaction "forms" is from the object that is being pushed.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, actually people don't interest on the reaction of electric force , So your answer will helpful either me and all  the people who interest in action- reaction force.

Comment: @OsalSelaka Any time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when [electromotiv force (emf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force) otherwise known as potenital difference or voltage exists between unequal amounts of electrical charge an electric field then exists which attracts charged particles of opposite polarity.  When these charged particles move in this direction, they are reacting to the electromotiv force.

The motion of charged particles in reaction to electromotiv force is known as electrical current.  The relationship between emf and current is defined by **[Ohms law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)**

R = V/I  where I is current measured in amperes, V is emf or voltage measured in volts, and R is resistance measured in ohms.  When electrical current flows through a conductor, the molecules within the medium are heated.  The greater the Resistance to current flow, the more heat is caused.  You can say the molecules are getting more average kinetic energy by reacting to the electrical current flow.

Also, there is reaction when electrical current or voltage is varied.  In electromagnetics, the term [**reactance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance) is used to describe either [**inductance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) or [**capacitance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance).  When electrical current is changed the reactance is inductance.  When electrical voltage is changed the reactance is capacitance.  These are defined by [Faraday's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) and [Maxwell's equations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations)